# Optimizing Bitwise for No Method Calls in Java

Tags: java, optimization, conditional-statements, bit-manipulation

I have some Java that contains a block of 64 lines like this:

```
x = ((some_long_bitwise_expression) << n |
     (same_long_bitwise_expression) >>> (32 - n))
```

where the "long expression" is identical within each line but changes from one line to the next. Normally this would just use a method call to compute the expression and then separately perform the bit rotation. But I'm wondering if this can be optimized and thus eliminate 64 method calls.

So is there some way to compute and save the expression product an then reference it on the other side of the OR?

If I just do:

```
int t;

x = ((t = (some_long_bitwise_expression)) << n |
     (t) >>> (32 - n))
```

this actually seems to work. But is it legit Java?

UPDATE:

After some simple performance tests I found that using 1 of 3 different method calls for each of the 64 lines of code was actually quite a bit faster.

Comment: Completely legit.

Comment: Is this way somehow preferable to setting `t` on  a separate line?

Comment: Or just write a separate `rotate` function

Comment: @phuclv No, use `Integer.rotate*` instead, as it's an intrinsic and gets optimized using an assembler rotate instruction (unlike your own method).

Answer (score 0):

```
int t;

x = ((t = (some_long_bitwise_expression)) << n |
     (t) >>> (32 - n))
```

For sure, you can do this obfuscation, but it's no better than

```
int t = some_long_bitwise_expression;    
x = (t << n) | (t >>> (32 - n));
```

which is much clearer. Moreover, the last expression is equivalent to

```
x = (t << n) | (t >>> -n);
```

as the shift distance is taken modulo 32 for ints. So you could write

```
x = rotateLeft(some_long_bitwise_expression, n)
```

with your own rotate method and have a very readable expression. You could even hope that it gets optimized using the rotate assembly instruction, but it doesn't. The Oracle JVM optimizes

```
x = Integer.rotateLeft(some_long_bitwise_expression, n)
```

but not your own method.